# Flex Mobile webView.loadURL() not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I have a stageWebView in my flex Mobile app. I am trying to call a javascript function passing along some arguments.

```
protected function list1_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                var list:List = event.target as List;
                var selectedString:String = list.selectedItem.label;
                webView.loadURL("javascript:doIt("+selectedString+")");
            }
```

Then I have my javascript code trying to use the selectedString I passed. It does not seem to be getting passed to the javascript. If I however pass a raw string like below it does work. Do I have quotes wrong or something else in the above code? Or can you not pass Objects from flexs?

```
protected function list1_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                var list:List = event.target as List;
                var selectedString:String = list.selectedItem.label;
                webView.loadURL("javascript:doIt('yeah')");
            }
```

EDIT
I had the quotes wrong.Should have been:

```
webView.loadURL("javascript:doIt('"+selectedString+"')");
```

Comment: I figured it out. Had the quotes messed up. Will update answer when able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
protected function list1_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            var list:List = event.target as List;
            var selectedString:String = list.selectedItem;
            var url:String = "javascript:doIt('" + selectedString + "')";
            webView.loadURL(url);
        }
```